# rgl: drawing a cube with colored faces, vertex points and lines

Tags: r, linear-algebra, rgl

To demonstrate the effect of linear transformations in 3D, `x -> A x`, I want to draw a cube and show its transformation under `A`.  For this, I need to color each face separately, and also show the vertex points and the lines that outline each face.

I can't figure out how to use distinct colors for the faces, and how to make this more general so I don't have to repeat all the steps for the result under the transformation.

what I tried:

```
library(rgl)
c3d <- cube3d(color=rainbow(6), alpha=0.5)
open3d()
shade3d(c3d)
points3d(t(c3d$vb), size=5)
for (i in 1:6)
    lines3d(t(c3d$vb)[c3d$ib[,i],])
```

This gives the image below.  But I don't understand how the faces are colored. And, I seem to have to use `points3d` and `lines3d` on the components of the `c3d` shape, and don't have a single object I can transform.

[image]

A particular transformation is given by the matrix `A` below, and here is how I add that to the scene,

```
A <- matrix(c( 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0,  1, 0, 2), 3, 3)
c3d_trans <- transform3d(c3d, A) 
shade3d( c3d_trans )
points3d(t(c3d_trans$vb), size=5)
```

This gives:

[image]

Is there some way to simplify this and make it more generally useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `rgl`, when drawing primitive shapes, you apply colours to vertices, not faces.  The faces are coloured by interpolating the colors at the vertices.

However, `cube3d()` is not a primitive shape, it's a "mesh".  It is drawn as 6 separate quadrilaterals.  Each vertex is used 3 times.

It's not really documented, but the order the colours are used is that the first 4 are used for one face, then the next 4 for the next face, etc.  If you want your colours to be `rainbow(6)`, you need to replicate each colour 4 times:

```
library(rgl)
c3d <- cube3d(color=rep(rainbow(6), each = 4), alpha = 0.5)
open3d()
shade3d(c3d)
points3d(t(c3d$vb), size = 5)
for (i in 1:6)
    lines3d(t(c3d$vb)[c3d$ib[,i],])
```

[image: Screenshot of rendered cube]

I'd recommend a higher `alpha` value; I find the transparency a little confusing at `alpha = 0.5`.

By the way, for the same purpose, I generally use a shape that looks more spherical as the baseline; I think it gives better intuition about the transformation.  Here's code I have used:

```
sphere <- subdivision3d(cube3d(color=rep(rainbow(6),rep(4*4^4,6)), alpha=0.9),
    depth=4)
sphere$vb[4,] <- apply(sphere$vb[1:3,], 2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))
open3d()
shade3d(sphere)
```

and this gives this shape:

[image: sphere]

which transforms to this:

```
A <- matrix(c( 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0,  1, 0, 2), 3, 3)
trans <- transform3d(sphere, A)
open3d()
shade3d(trans)
```

[image: transformed sphere]

Of course, it all looks better if you can rotate it.

Comment: It would be nice if this behavior of color was documented. It was also not obvious how to draw the points and lines. Perhaps my example could be used to illustrate these things.

Comment: Why not submit a patch to the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

(Note: I use `rgl version 0.96.0`. If my memory is correct, `wire3d()` and `dot3d()` rules have been changed)

It isn't a good idea to give a color informatin when you make a class `mesh3d` object, because `shade3d()`, `wire3d()` and `dot3d()` use it in  the different ways. It would be better to give plot-function a color information when you draw a object.

for example;

```
A <- matrix(c( 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0,  1, 0, 2), 3, 3)
c3d2 <- cube3d()
c3d_trans2 <- cube3d(A)
colv <- rep(2:7, each=4)

shade3d(c3d2, col = colv, alpha = 0.8)
wire3d(c3d2); dot3d(c3d2, size = 5)
shade3d(c3d_trans2, col = colv, alpha=0.5)
dot3d(c3d_trans2, size = 5)
```

[image]

---

**[ the details related to colors and mesh3d.obj ]**

Most important rule is that **a vertex consumes a color** whenever it is used (but it is a bit complex, please see below exampe). I call below matrix **ib** and `mesh3d.obj$vb`'s col number **index** .

```
cube3d()$ib
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    3    2    1    1    5
# [2,]    3    7    4    5    2    6
# [3,]    4    8    8    7    6    8
# [4,]    2    4    6    3    5    7
```

**shade3d() rule** (it's easy)

```
plot3d(cube3d(scaleMatrix(1.2,1.2,1.2)), alpha=0)
text3d(t(cube3d()$vb[1:3,]*1.05), texts=1:8)  # indices
shade3d(cube3d(), col=c(rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4), rep(5,4), rep(6,4), rep(7,4)), alpha=0.8)
                #  ib[1:4, 1]  [1:4, 2]  [1:4, 3]  [1:4, 4]  [1:4, 5]  [1:4, 6]
              # index 1,3,4,2  3,7,8,4   2,4,8,6, ...
```

[image]

**wire3d rule** (complex and terrible..; edited)

```
text3d(t(cube3d()$vb[1:3,]*1.05), texts=1:8, font=2)  # indices
wire3d(cube3d(), col=c(rep(2,6), rep(3,6), rep(4,6), rep(5,6), rep(6,6), rep(7,6)))
# I gave each color 6 times.

index  1       3       4       2       1
ib$[1,1] - [2,1] - [3,1] - [4,1] - [1,1] - NA
 col   2       2       2       2       2    2  # Why NA uses a color!!??

index  3       7      8    4 (skipped) 3       # the line already has been drawn, skipped.
ib$[1,2] - [2,2] - [3,2] - [4,2] - [1,2] - NA; 
 col   3       3      3    3 (skipped) 3    3

index 2 (sk)   4 (sk)  8       6      2
ib$[1,3] - [2,3] - [3,3] - [4,3] - [1,3] - NA; 
 col 4  (sk)   4 (sk)  4       4       4    4,   and so on.
```

In one `ib`'s `col`, one vertex have only one color (e.g., at `ib[,1]`, Index3's color information is used both 1-3 and 3-4. When the line already has been drawn, it is skipped. It is **too difficult (some patterns is impossible)** to draw lines in different colors using `wire3d()`. If you want to do, it would be better to use `lines3d()` or `segments3d()`

[image]

**dot3d rule**

```
plot3d(cube3d(scaleMatrix(1.2,1.2,1.2)), alpha=0)
text3d(t(cube3d()$vb[1:3,]*1.05), texts=1:8)  # indices
dot3d(cube3d(), col=1:8, size=8)

unique(c(cube3d()$ib))
# [1] 1 3 4 2 7 8 6 5
```

if you give `col=1:8`, NOT index2 but index3 becomes `col = 2` (`red`).
So, `col = c("col1", "col2", ..., "col8")[unique(c(object$ib))]` means index1 is `col1`, index2 is `col2`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The second part of my question-- how to generalize this a bit -- was unanswered.  Here is a simple function I'm now using to make the steps reusable.

```
# draw a mesh3d object with vertex points and lines
draw3d <- function(object, ...) {
    shade3d(object, ...)
    vertices <- t(object$vb)
    indices <- object$ib
    points3d(vertices, size=5)
    for (i in 1:ncol(indices))
        lines3d(vertices[indices[,i],])
}
```